# Play 2.4 to 2.5 netty issues while testing

Tags: playframework

Getting a

```
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.rejectedExecution - Failed to 
    submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down? 
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
```

Using deprecated WS.url() for all requests in tests. The issue is that when testing all 100 tests, the last 3 fail. However, running just those 3 tests individually, they will pass.

Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: We will need to see your tests.

Comment: Play 2.5.2 seemed to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue in 2.5.6 ..

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing this in my logs with Play 2.5.9